# How to stop angular cli uglification?

Tags: angular6

I use angular 6 cli.

when i run ng build -- prod
the class name gets minified in 't' name and this creates difficulties in using 'constructor.name'.

tests/results:

1. ng build --prod --build-optimizer=false // Not resolve problem.
2. ng eject, mangle=false // bad option.
3. extend classes className property (className = this.constructor.name) // undesirable option
4. your suggestion???